# Can not reboot after building xenomai kernel

Tags: kernel, ramdisk, xenomai, adeos

After building a vanilla kernel with Xenomai 3 Cobalt Core to my x86-based PC, I reboot to choose this new kernel on GRUB. However, the screen freezes while initializing ramdisk process.

- I installed modules and installed the image on my Ubuntu 14.04 OS.
- I also tried to install Xenomai in different kernels (3.18.13 or 3.14.44) the result did not change.
  Even on a different machine with the same architecture, the problem **persists**.

---

I am assuming the problem is about patching **Xenomai** or the **Xenomai i-pipe** to Kernel because I could build and install the unpatched versions.